# Why are there no tags for Google Stadia or NBA 2K21?

Tags: support, tags

I tried to create tags "stadia" and "nba2k21" but don't have 300 reputation points so was blocked.

Could someone please create them?

Answer (score 4):

In order for a tag to exist, a question needs to exist first. Go ahead and ask your question with a placeholder tag like [pc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pc) and someone with 300 rep will come along and create the appropriate tag shortly.

Comment: Thanks. Question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376091/controller-configuration-for-nba-2k21-on-stadia